# How to count child data from another table and display in parent tables?

Tags: php, mysql, treeview

Iam using treeview, I want to count data and display on child, but that parent can display a sum of childs and so on

I have 2 tables:

```
table_estruc has (id - text - parent_id)
table_resp has (field_id, field_name, id, parent_id)
```

I can count of all records on `table_resp` where `table_estuc.id = table_resp.id`, even count to be display in parent id, but what I can´t acchieve is to count reconds and display them on then parant id of current `parent_id` and so on.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `estructura_set`";
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));?>
```

```
<?php $a = $row["area"];
      $cct = $row["cct"];
      $mid = $row["id"];
      $mparenid = $row["parent_id"];

    $promovidos_tot_query2 = "SELECT COUNT tbl_promotor_parent_id, (promov.tbl_promovido_ID) as promo2 FROM tbl_promovidos promov INNER JOIN tbl_promotores pmt ON pmt.tbl_promotor_ID = promov.tbl_promovido_promotor_ID
    WHERE pmt.tbl_promotor_eid= '$mid'";
    $res2 = mysqli_query($conn, $promovidos_tot_query2) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));
    $total_promov2 = $res2->fetch_assoc();
    $promovidos2 = $total_promov2['promo2'];
    $promovidosp = $total_promov2['tbl_promotor_parent_id'];


$promo = $promovidos2;
$sualternos = $promovidos3;
$grantotal = $promo + $sualternos;

$promo = $promovidos2;
$sualternos = $promovidos3;
$grantotal = $promo + $sualternos;

$row["text"] = $row["text"].' - ('.$row["cct"].') <span class="badge badge-primary"> Promovidos <span class="badge badge-light">'. $promo.'</span></span> 
        <span class="badge badge-primary"> Subalternos <span class="badge badge-light">'. $sualternos .'</span></span>
        <span class="badge badge-primary"> Total <span class="badge badge-light">'. $grantotal .'</span></span>';

$data[] = $row; 
     }
```

Comment: your text description of tables don't match the table names in your PHP. Please fix and show the expected output of your query with sample data.

Comment: What version of MySQL? (version 8 offers  window functions)

Comment: 5.7.21, on wamp server